# Mysql выборка за год по месяцам с суммой данных по каждому месяцу

Tags: mysql

Написал запрос

```
SELECT
  var1.`date`,
  var1.`field_value` as name,
  var2.`field_value` as value,
  var1.`line_number`
FROM
  `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var1
 JOIN
  `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var2
  ON (var1.`line_number` = var2.`line_number`)AND (var1.`exchange_number` = var2.`exchange_number`)AND (var1.`id_variable`<>var2.`id_variable`)AND(var1.`id_variable` = 1) AND(var2.`id_variable` = 2)
WHERE var1.`field_value` = 'Итого по Компании' AND var1.`date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

Получаю вот такое содержимое таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сложить сумму всех данных за 2021-04, за 2021-05 и т.д.? В ступоре уже.. Поля line_number и name не сильно важны, вывел их для себя

Comment: `GROUP BY` же для этого есть, только сконструируйте строку, по которой группировать будете

Comment: получить из даты год и месяц и по ним группировать

Comment: Не знаю, правильно это или нет, но сделал так. Сейчас прикреплю свой вариант решения

Answer (score 0):

Вот так запрос работает и делает то что мне нужно на данный момент

```
SELECT
     EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM var1.`date`) as dates,
      var2.`field_value` as value
    FROM
      `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var1
     JOIN
      `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var2
      ON (var1.`line_number` = var2.`line_number`)AND (var1.`exchange_number` = var2.`exchange_number`)AND (var1.`id_variable`<>var2.`id_variable`)AND(var1.`id_variable` = 1) AND(var2.`id_variable` = 2)
    WHERE var1.`field_value` = 'Итого по Компании' AND var2.`field_value` IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY dates
```

Comment: Ну да, как-то так и надо делать.

Comment: А можно ли потом манипулировать этими данными? Например: я хочу построить график на основе этих данных с возможностью выбора периода по месяцам. Можно ли сделать этот запрос вложенным для другого запроса?